# Python Django ..with unicode and str

Tags: python, django

I have problem with my website on Django.

In my PC I used PyCharm on Windows - all work. Form data = str, on my server = unicode..

Error on my server:

```
TypeError at /result
descriptor 'split' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'
```

my code:

```
text = request.POST['text']
sentences = str.split(text, ".")
```

On Windows all work, on server - ubuntu - not work

Answer (score 2):

`str.split` is calling the `split` method defined on the `str` class, but the object you're passing it -- `text` -- is a `unicode` object.

Luckily, `split` is also defined on `unicode` objects, and you can just call it directly, like this:

```
sentences = text.split(".")
```